# Extracting specific entries from multiple list to a single lsit python

Tags: python

I have 3 lists as follows:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = ["45a","23b","123c","4342d","234a","453z","234a","453e","12r"]
l3 = [4,5,6]
```

I want to create a list that consecutively takes a single entry from `l1` and `l3`, whereas for `l2` the entry starts when *"a"* appears in strings and all the consecutive element goes with it until *"a"* appears again, from where the second entry begins.

I have tried some for "loop" and string and substring methods but have not found a solution.
Regards and many thanks for your comments

Comment: Can you include your expected output

Comment: It is hard to understand the problem statement, are you using the entry in l1 or l3 to find instances of it in l2 at the same time, or only one at a time? The expected output is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be helpful:

```
l2 = ["45a","23b","123c","4342d","234a","453z","234a","453e","12r"]
indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(l2) if x[-1] == 'a'] + [len(l2)]
chunks = [l2[i:j] for i, j in zip(indexes, indexes[1:])]

print(chunks)
# [['45a', '23b', '123c', '4342d'], ['234a', '453z'], ['234a', '453e', '12r']]
```